# Regex split 3 string and 2 int

Tags: php, regex

I have 2 type of String.

One is like this

```
Text Text Text+24 2009 2
```

The other type is

```
Text text 2005 2
```

I would like to split these 2 typologies of strings in this way

```
Text Text Text+24
2009
2
```

OR

```
Text text
2005
2
```

The text portion may vary, but in any case you have 2 numeric values at the end.

EDIT: I tried to do something like that

```
preg_match_all("/.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+)/is", $txt, $matches)
```

Unfortunately I can not understand how to work with regex

Comment: The idea is .... You code something, and if you cannot get it to work, .... we help. The idea is NOT ... you ask us to do it all for you

Comment: Edit the first comment, thanks :)

Comment: Try `preg_match('~^(.*)\s(\d{4})\s+(\d)$~', $s, $matches)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
^(.*?)\h+(\d+)\h+(\d+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JqnwnT/3)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/^(.*?)\h+(\d+)\h+(\d+)$/m';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^ - Start
(.*?) - Match and capture 0 or more of any character (lazy)
\h+ - Match 1 or more horizontal whitespace
(\d+) - Match & capture 1 or more digits
\h+ - Match 1 or more horizontal whitespace
(\d+) - Match & capture 1 or more digits
$ - End
```

Comment: Thanks +1. It works perfectly. Would you suggest a link to be able to understand how the regex works?

Comment: I added fill breakup of my regex. Moreover I have added a demo link of regex in action. That link also explains all the details of this regex.

Comment: Great work.. +1

Comment: Thanks so much @SahilGulati